# Making a timer for an LCD screen using C

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to make a timer for an LCD screen. I don't normally program because it isn't related to my degree but I thought I would do it for fun. I am using a built in library designed by a friend.
I have designed the if loop below, just some quick info on my loop.
The `LCD_cursor` statement moves the cursor around the screen so I can print the letter in the correct place. 
The `LCD_display_value` function is used to print the value of the integer.

The problem that I have is, it prints everything fine until it gets to `time2`, then it just skips the 10 digits and carries on as normal. It works at finishing the loop at the right point.

```
time1 = 1; time2 = 4; time3 = 4; finish = 3;        
while (finish != 1) {
    if (time1 == 0 && time2 == 0 && time3 == 0)
        finish = 1;
    if (time1 != 0)
        time1 = time1 - 1;
    else {time2 = time2 - 1;
                                    time1 = 9;}

    if (time2 == 0){
        LCD_cursor(14,0);
        LCD_display_value(time2);
        Delay_ms(200);

        if (time3 != 0){
            time2 = 5;
            time3 = time3 - 1;
            time1 = 9;
        }
    }

    LCD_cursor(15,0);
    LCD_display_value(time1);
    LCD_cursor(14,0);
    LCD_display_value(time2);
    LCD_cursor(13,0);
    LCD_putch(':');
    LCD_cursor(12,0);
    LCD_display_value(time3);
    delay_ms(200);
}
```

Comment: There certainly is a place for creative text design. But not for program code.

Comment: time2 does equal to 0, but when it equals to 0 time1 doesn't go and do its full count down from 9.

Comment: @Olaf I'm kind of confused by your comment

Comment: As much as I am by the creative formatting of you rsource code.

Comment: Mr. @Olaf If you think you can help me solve this problem that i am running into i will be more than happy to give you the entire C source code where i get the LCD_cursor() and LCD_display_value() functions.

Comment: What does "it skips the 10 digits" mean?

Comment: @immibis So when ever the time goes like 2:0x it suddenly goes to 1:59. Timer1 doesn't show up at all when timer 0 is at 0.

Comment: @Badprogrammer Next time try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for your case it could have been generated by replacing the all the LCD functions with `printf("%d:%d%d\n", time3, time2, time1)`

Comment: The thing is i do have it working in visual studios but when i transfer the file onto the PIC and use the specific libraries to display the numbers it doesn't seem to work.
`int a = 9;
int b = 3;
int c = 2;
int d = 3;


main() {
 
 while (d != 1){

  printf("%d : %d %d\n", c, b, a);
  a = a - 1;
  if (a < 0){
   b = b - 1;
   a = 9;
  }
  if (b < 0){
   c = c - 1;
   b = 5;
   a = 9;
  }

  if (c < 0)
   d = 1;

 }
 getch();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (time2 == 0)
```

to

```
if (time2 == 0 && time1==0)
```

---

Rearranging your code blocks you also can fix your exit condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int time1 = 1;
int time2 = 4;
int time3 = 4;

while (time1 || time2 || time3) {

    if (time1 != 0)
        time1 = time1 - 1;
    else {
        time2 = time2 - 1;
        time1 = 9;
         }

    printf("%d:%d%d\n", time3, time2, time1);

    if (time2 == 0 && time1 == 0){

        if (time3 != 0){
            time2 = 5;
            time3 = time3 - 1;
            time1 = 9;
            printf("inner %d:%d%d\n", time3, time2, time1);
        }
    }

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. @xvan! 
That works! 
I understand my question wasn't as clear as i had hope and i will try to make a better effort to explain my question more clearly in the future. 
Once again thank you :)